# How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation

I'm running Mountain Lion and the basic default Python version is 2.7. I downloaded Python 3.3 and want to set it as default.

Currently:

```
$ python
    version 2.7.5
$ python3.3
    version 3.3
```

How do I set it so that every time I run `$ python` it opens 3.3?

Comment: You can manage the version of python with `pyenv`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac

Answer (score 662, accepted):

Changing the default python executable's version system-wide could break some applications that depend on python2.

However, you can alias the commands in most shells, Since the default shells in macOS (bash in 10.14 and below; zsh in 10.15) share a similar syntax. You could put
`alias python='python3'`
in your `~/.profile`, and then source `~/.profile` in your `~/.bash_profile` and/or  your`~/.zsh_profile` with a line like:

```
[ -e ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile
```

This way, your alias will work across shells.

With this, `python` command now invokes `python3`. If you want to invoke the "original" python (that refers to *python2*) on occasion, you can use `command python`, which will leaving the alias untouched, and works in all shells.

If you launch interpreters more often *(I do)*, you can always create more aliases to add as well, i.e.:

```
alias 2='python2'
alias 3='python3'
```

---

Tip: For scripts, instead of using a shebang like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This way, the system will use python3 for running python ***executables***.

Comment: Should this not be put in ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bash_aliases?

Comment: Putting `alias python=python3` and then running `python` in my terminal on osx el capitan didn't work for me. Tried saving it both ~/.bash_aliases and ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: @Haymaker87 run `source  ~/.bash_profile` after edit `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: You can do the same for pip: `alias pip='pip3.6'`

Comment: @surfer190 that will cause problem when running with sudo, isn't it?

Comment: @SantoshKumar If you're using virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper for activation do you still need to use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or any other shebang + path at the top of python files?

Comment: Is this everything that is required for me to switch to python3 in my shell and applications?

Comment: @Alper this was for shell only. The tip part is for developers, but don't change if either one of them is already there. It might break.

Comment: Shouldn't cause any issues with sudo but will cause issues if you don't source your alias.  This is more of a workaround.

Comment: It won't take until you close your terminal window after the change to the .bash_profile are made.

Comment: you should set the pip alias not to pip3.6 specifically, instead set it to pip3: 
``alias pip='pip3'

Comment: adding -> alias python='python3' in ~/.bash_profile file worked for me.

Comment: Would it still break things now in Catalina?

Comment: Nope, its *bash* thing. Nothing to do with the operating system.

Comment: Do I need to `source ~/.bash_profile` everytime i close and open my terminal? It says command not found after I re-opened my terminal

Comment: Whilst this is a quick fix there are some potential issues with this solution, especially because you still depend on the python version Apple ships by default. [This article](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) explains them in depth as well as alternative solutions that avoid these problems.

Answer (score 232):

You can solve it by symbolic link.

```
unlink /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (aliases are nice but only accessible by bash, which limits where you can call from).  However, I would use `unlink` instead of `rm` to remove symlinks (if you accidentally add a trailing slash on `rm` you might have some bad results).  Alternatively, you could do `ln -s -f ...` which should overwrite the current symlink.

Comment: @ChadBefus Thank you for your reply. I agree with your opinion. unlink is safer than rm.

Comment: Does it have any consequences for scripts that expect `python` to be `python2.7`?

Comment: Can you do the reverse to reestablish python2x as the default version? So if you have linked python with python3, I'm suggesting then you can unlink python3 and ln -s python2.

Comment: it does nothing

Comment: macOS: `unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @MarksCode try to just run the second original line (i.e. `ln -s...` *with* `/local/`).

Comment: If your app requires python3 for running, you should edit symlinks not alias.

Comment: For Mac OS users, you should use the brew commands to make the symlinks automatically. For example: brew unlink python, brew switch python 3.x.x_x (or 2.x.x), brew python link python (or python@2). Note, brew installs python 3 as "python3".

Comment: This did not work for me. After following this still python2 is invoked by default.

Comment: Doesn't this risks the application dependent on python2? Definitely it will go away when Python 3 is mainstream, but still. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: The *real* major problem with recent Mac OSs is it doesn't give a $#%^ about UNIX commands and notion of root: 

`>> sudo unlink /usr/bin/python`

`Password:`

`unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

`>> sudo -su root`

`>> whoami`

`root`

`>> unlink /usr/bin/python`

`unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

Comment: This feels like the cleaner approach. I set mine to python 3.5 and it worked.

Comment: I had to close terminal and open a new one to get it working in macOS

Comment: I had to do this in my case ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.11/bin /usr/local/bin/python3

Answer (score 155):

Open **~/.bash_profile** file.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then put the alias as follows:

```
alias python='python3'
```

Now save the file and then run the **~/.bash_profile** file.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Congratulation !!! Now, you can use python3 by typing **python**.

```
python --version
```

Python 3.7.3

Comment: If you found like I did that the same issue applies for pip (i.e. the pip --version is still 2.7.x) then you'll need to do the same steps for pip3.  vi ~/.bash_profile, alias pip='pip3', source ~/.bash_profile, pip --version

Comment: Do I really need to `source ~/.bash_profile` everytime I re-opened my terminal? It reverts to python2 once I close and open the terminal again.

Comment: @RickyAguilar Me either. My current conda base is 3.8, I want to change the default pythton to 3.10. I have changed the `~/.bash_profile`, by commenting out the existing one and adding 
`export PATH="/Applications/anaconda3/envs/py3.10/bin:$PATH"` 
it works after `source`. However, once I quite the terminal and reopen, it turns out the base is still py3.8. and i need to `source` again. Which is unresonable. Since I can `conda activate py3.10`. Have u find another way to tackle this?

Comment: if you already installed visual studio code it will be easy to use. `code ~/.bash_profile` instead of using. `vi ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Just this code worked for my Mac, thanks

Answer (score 149):

I encountered this issue as well, so I thought I should post an updated answer. Please note that this will only apply to a Mac-based setup (I haven't tried it with Windows or any flavor of Linux). The simplest way to get this working is to install Python via [Brew](https://brew.sh/). If you don't have brew installed, you will need to do that first. Once installed, do the following in at the terminal:

```bash
brew install python
```

This will install Python 3. After it's installed, run this:

```bash
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

You will see all of the links created by brew to its Python install. It will look something like this:

```bash
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  36 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  43 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3-config@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  38 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3.7@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  45 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  39 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3.7m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  46 Oct  1 13:35 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config@ -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/bin/python3.7m-config
```

The first row in this example shows the `python3` symlink. To set it as the default `python` symlink run the following:

```bash
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Similarly you can set the pip symlink too

```bash
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

You will have to reload your current terminal shell to use the new symlink in that shell. Run this command to reload your shell:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

You're all set now. Now, you can do:

```bash
which python
```

and it should show:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/python
```

All newly opened shell sessions will (should) automatically use the new symlink. To test this, open a new terminal shell and run the following:

```bash
python --version
```

Comment: Works great ([Reference](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf))

Comment: "You will have to reload your current terminal shell for it to use the new symlink in that shell." Thanks, that was the piece I was missing from all the answers so far.

Comment: this also worked for me. A few things I would like to add - 1. I am using Mac M1, so I had to run `arch -arm64 brew install python` & 2. pip wasn't working for me, so I had to run `sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip` and then pip worked.

Comment: @sohammondal Thanks you. I appreciate your input.

Comment: Works great on Intel iMac Pro (2017). It fixed the issue I was having of not being able to update following the other answers above.

Comment: Following my comment yesterday I have discovered that, after I quit the terminal, the changes do not stick. How do you make the changes permanent?

Comment: but I'm getting.   'zsh: no matches found: /usr/local/bin/python*'  
  this error after running    'ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*'

Comment: I tried many solutions and this was the only one that worked - thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 37):

Go to terminal type:

```
alias python=python3.x
```

This will setup default python as python3.x

Comment: This worked for me but using "alias python=python3"

Comment: This will temporarily set python version for that terminal instance.

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me. I added **alias** and restarted my **terminal**:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 17):

The following worked for me

```
cd /usr/local/bin
mv python python.old
ln -s python3 python
```

Answer (score 12):

Go to 'Applications', enter 'Python' folder, there should be a bash script called 'Update Shell Profile.command' or similar. Run that script and it should do it.

Update: It looks like you should not update it: [how to change default python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version)

Answer (score 11):

I believe most of people landed here are using ZSH thorugh iterm or whatever, and that brings you to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/847543).

You have to add/modify your commands in `~/.zshrc` instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ sudo ln -s -f $(which python3) $(which python)
```

done.

Comment: ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted

Comment: ln: found: No such file or directory

Comment: usage: ln [-s [-F] | -L | -P] [-f | -i] [-hnv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-s [-F] | -L | -P] [-f | -i] [-hnv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file

Comment: @dy_  your comment is unclear.    just try:  `sudo ln -s -f $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python`

Answer (score 10):

Mac users just need to run the following code on terminal

```
brew switch python 3.X.X
```

**3.x.x** should be the new python version.

This will update all the system links.

**UPDATE**

For Newer version of MAC use

```
brew link python 3.X.X
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote. This worked for me! Thanks for posing this. I upvoted you to cancel that down vote ;)

Comment: On Catalina (10.15.17), I get: `Error: Calling \`brew switch\` is disabled! Use \`brew link\` @-versioned formulae instead.`

Comment: this does not work for me

Comment: Error: Unknown command: switch

Comment: For me it looked like this: `brew link python@3.9`. Thanks for hints!

Comment: This does not work for Python 3.10.5, please could you post a solution that is not dependent on brew?

Comment: On Monterey it gives me this error: `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/3.11.4`

Answer (score 9):

Suggestions to alias python to python3 will cause problems with virtual environments that set the version of python (eg: pyenv). With pyenv, you can set the version globally like so:

```
pyenv global 3.8.2
```

and then in any specific project, you can create a .python-version file which has the python version inside of it:

```
pyenv local 2.7.1
```

This is the best way to manage multiple versions of python on a system in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

## On MacOS

Step-1: Upgrade python to latest version by:
$ brew upgrade python

Step-2: Go to home:
$ cd

Step-3: open .bash_profile

$ vi .bash_profile

## Setting PATH for Python 3.8

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Step-4: Save the file. And compile it by:

$ . .bash_profile

Step-5: Check the python version:

$ python -V

Step-6: Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

I think when you install python it puts export path statements into your ~/.bash_profile file. So if you do not intend to use Python 2 anymore you can just remove that statement from there. Alias as stated above is also a great way to do it.

Here is how to remove the reference from ~/.bash_profile 
- vim ./.bash_profile
- remove the reference (AKA something like: export PATH="/Users/bla/anaconda:$PATH")
- save and exit
- source ./.bash_profile to save the changes

Comment: It does not happen

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way from my exp. (if you have brew installed on your mac).

Try this from your terminal:

`brew install python3`

and then run the below on your terminal :

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*`

**Tip:**

** (*note down the python version 3.8 or 3.9 thats displayed on the terminal. This will be required in the next step). for e.g. in my case it was:*

lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  24 May  7 14:33 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.9

Now run the below command on your terminal:

`ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python`

*(where 3.9 is the version displayed on your terminal with the previous command)*

Its DONE !

To test your default version of python:

1. close the current terminal or start a new terminal and
2. run the below command :

`python --version`

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was using PyCharm and setting the default python version to the the one that i need to work with.

install PyCharm and go to file ==> preferences for new project, then choose the interpreter you want for your projects, in this case python 3.3

Answer (score 2):

If you use macports, you do not need to play with aliases or environment variables, just use the method macports already offers, explained by this Q&A:

[How to: Macports select python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python)

TL;DR:

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is available on OS X, but on linux I would make use of the `module` command.  [See here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/module).

Set up the modulefile correctly, then add something like this to your rc file (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
module load python3.3
```

This will make it so that your paths get switched around as required when you log in without impacting any system defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using macports, that has a easier way to do:

run:

*`port install python37`*

after install, set default:

*`sudo port select --set python python37`*

*`sudo port select --set python3 python37`*

restart your cmd window, finished.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on M1 Mac

Answer (score 1):

Well... It's kinda old. But still deserves a good answer.

And the good one is **You Don't Wanna Touch The Default Python On Mac.**

Install any Python version you need via Homebrew or whatever and use it in virtualenv. Virtualenv is often considered to be something crap-like, but it's still way, wayyyy better than changing python version system-wide (macOS is likely to protect itself from such actions) or user-wide, bash-wide... whatever. Just forget about the default Python. Using playgrounds like venv is what your OS will be most, very most grateful for.

The case is, for example, many modern Linux distributions get rid of Python2 installed out-of-the-box, leaving only Python3 in the system. But everytime you try to install something old with python2 as a dependency... hope you understand what I mean. A good developer doesn't care. Good developers create clean playgrounds with python version they desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `virtualenvwrapper`, you can just locate it using `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`, then open it using `vim` or any other editor then change the following

```
# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.
if [ "${VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON:-}" = "" ]
then
    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
fi
```

Change the line `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"` to `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3)"`.