# Setting Python path in OS X

Tags: python, osx-mavericks

I played around a bit with my Python installations in **OS X Mavericks**.

I searched for all files which contained "python2.7" and deleted them. Now i want to point to my current Python version, which is 3.3.2.

When i type in `python`, i am getting this:

```
python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory
```

My folder for my Python installation looks like this:

[image]

There is **no Python-Path** set in my `.bash_profile` file.

> Where can i change the current Version of Python?

EDIT: Where i got the new version from? `sudo pyenv install 3.3.2`

EDIT: The result of `which python`:

[image]

Comment: You've just deleted your default Python installation? It doesn't seem to be a great idea... Where did you get Python 3.3 from?

Comment: what happens if you type `which python`?  Presumably it's a symbolic link to a now-deleted executable.  By the way, in the future, you can have multiple python versions coexisting on the same machine...  There is no reason to completely delete the old version.

Comment: And 'python' not pointing to Python 2.7 can really confuse some scripts.

Comment: @cubuspl42 i've edited my post: from pyenv. mgilson: i've edited my post. cubuspl42: Why?

Comment: Can i delete python completely and install it from the ground up?

Comment: Because some of (especially older) scripts just assume that `python` means `python27`. I really encourage you to use something like Macports or Homebrew to install *nix stuff (like Python) on your Mac. Then just have `/usr/local/bin/` before `/usr/bin/` in your PATH.
You shouldn't have deleted it at all. Now leave it as is and try Homebrew (IMO, the right) way to install Python.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't delete the built in Python from the computer. There are applications that use  Python 2, so deleting it would break them. I installed Python 3 in parallel to python 2.7.

Also not a good idea to point version 2.7 frameworks at version 3 frameworks for the above reasons. It will make for unnecessary confusion and mess that will be likely to cause issues.

Did you check out the configuration section here:

http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/mac.html

Section 4.1.3 mentions needing to changed environment variables to point to your version of Python that you want to be the default.

As well, here's how to create an alias to make Python 3 easy to access:

[How to set Python's default version to 3.3 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/mac-set-default-python-version-to-3-3)

Don't take this the wrong way, but I would try to undo most of what you've done so far, before you get too far ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a solution to install Python completely new. I had to use the [official installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/) from the [Python-Website](http://www.python.org).

1. **I've downloaded the intaller and installed Python.**
2. **I moved the new installation to the Python-Versions-Folder:**

   sudo mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
3. **Setting the group to *wheel* :**

   sudo chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
4. **Updating the current link:**

   sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current

   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
5. **Removing old copies**

   sudo rm /usr/bin/pydoc

   sudo rm /usr/bin/python

   sudo rm /usr/bin/pythonw

   sudo rm /usr/bin/python-config
6. **Creating the new sym-links:**

   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc /usr/bin/pydoc

   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/python

   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw /usr/bin/pythonw

   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config /usr/bin/python-config

[[Source]](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/)

Comment: this was good stuff, sadly it didn't work for me; I'm getting a nasty "The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install"