# Unable to create a virtual environment in osx

Tags: macos, virtualenv, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a new virtual environment in OSX. This is what I have tried:

```
lucas-MacBook-Pro:MyApps lucapuggini$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
lucas-MacBook-Pro:MyApps lucapuggini$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 python_3_6_scipy_dev
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory




lucas-MacBook-Pro:~ lucapuggini$ brew install python3.5
Error: No available formula with the name "python3.5" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
lucas-MacBook-Pro:~ lucapuggini$
```

Comment: Looks like you may need to install python 3.5

Comment: You can't install it because it looks like it's not in brew's repositories. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665924/3980985 for installation instructions

Comment: I think you might have a version of venv for python 3.5, check that you have the right venv version for your python version

Comment: Since you have almost 3k rep you should know this but, Stackoverflow is not for helping you install software, it is for solving specific errors. It is now up to you to do searches and figure out how to determine if you have the right version of venv.

Comment: all the above comments can be removed as irrelevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved with `python3 -m venv <myenvname>` as explained [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544)