# How to set path for latest version of Python on mac

Tags: python, path, version

I have downloaded latest Python version 3.5 on my Mac OSX 10.9.5. It is stored in `Applications`. If I type `python --version` in Terminal, I get `Python 2.7.5` which is in directory `/usr/bin/`. How can I set path for `Python 3.5`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python's default version to 3.3 in Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-in-mac)

Comment: Close, however I prefer no-alias solutions.

Comment: If you want something more solid, even though it's more advanced, you should look into [homebrew](http://brew.sh) (package manager) to install python and , optionally, [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to set up self-contained environments

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps.

1. Find the location of the new python
2. delete the /usr/bin/python
3. set export PATH=$PATH:$new_python_location
4. Type python --version

Comment: How can I do step 2? I tried "rm -Rf python" resulting in "Permission denied". It seems that /usr/bin/python is protected (properties -rwxr-xr-x).

Comment: execute sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python

Comment: I don't understand step 3: new python location is "/Applications/Python\ 3.5/". Do I have to enter "export python=$python:$/Applications/Python\ 3.5/"? Looks like I understood it wrong.

Comment: we have to set the path of new python location. to set the python location, the command is: export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Python\ 3.5/bin

Comment: I don't succeed. I enter "export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Python\ 3.5/bin" and no /usr/bin/python is generated. It is still missing.

Comment: it will not generate /usr/bin/python. But if you type python --version, it will give the result. If you want to generate /usr/bin/python, you have to create symbolic link.