# Python third party Module global import

Tags: python, import, module

i'm currently into learning a bit of python and i want to import the paperclip third party module into my python file.

Yes, i already installed the pyperclip module with 
`pip install pyperclip`.

if i create a file on my desktop, i get an error which says 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named pyperclip`

However if i put the test.py in my python folder, it runs.

The question now is, is there a way to make all my installed modules available on a global scope ? I just want to have my file e.g. on my Desktop and run it without having import issues.

Thank you.

Greetings

Edit: I'm working on a Mac, maybe this leads to the problem

Comment: ... are you launching the file using `python3.5`? If you install the module for python3.5 and then use python2 or python3.4 to run the code obviously the interpreter wont find the module...

Comment: To be clear: if you have properly installed the module using `pip` and you are properly launching the file with the right interpreter the module **will** be available independently of your current working directory. The fact that you get an `ImportError` means you either messed up the installation or you are using the wrong interpreter to run the code.

Comment: `$ pip install pyperclip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyperclip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`


`$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named paperclip`


`$ python3.5 test.py 
  File "test.py", line 3
    print pyperclip.paste()
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

(Also changed the code above )

Comment: Reading [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) it looks like that *On Mac, this module makes use of the pbcopy and pbpaste commands, which should come with the os.*.  maybe you don't have those installed? Try to install `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` (these are *not* python modules, but Macs programs).

Comment: both pbcopy and pbpaste are installed.

Comment: Also, i uninstalled pyperclip and reinstalled it, still same problem...

Comment: That "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error you're getting is because `test.py` uses Python 2 style `print` statements, which were removed from Python 3.  Also, double-check your spelling --- both "pyperclip" and "p**a**perclip" have appeared in your question and in the comment I'm replying to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

The `pip install`automatically used `pip3.5 install` 
whereas `python test.py`didn't use `python3.5 test.py`

Thank you @Bakurìu

Is there a way i can define `python3.5`as `python`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

pip3.5 install paperclip

pyperclip is install but not paperclip

Comment: If you look at the error message it has `import pyperclip`. The error is probably because the OP incorrectly manually wrote the error here.

Comment: Yes, but paperclip is call by pyperclip I think, and when pyperclip try to import, it generate this exception

Comment: `pip` installs dependencies too. At least it should.

Comment: Thank you, yes it was a type, i'm sorry.