# Python 3.5 running in IDLE shell, but not macOS Terminal

Tags: python, macos, shell, pip, python-idle

I'm trying to get Python 3.5 to run in my terminal.  I made a script using idle that printed out the version of python in use to try to solve my problem. The script looked like this:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

When I ran it in IDLE, I got the following output:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

When I ran it in terminal, I got the following output instead:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

I want to be able to run my scripts in terminal because I want to be able to access files and use pip.  If you know how I can do one or both of these things in the IDLE shell, or you know how to update terminal so I can do this.

Comment: Try `python3` instead of `python` in the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Running Python from the terminal

If you have Python installed, then:

- `python` or `python2` opens the interactive prompt or runs a script if a file is supplied as an argument
- `python3` does the same as above, but for Python 3

Note that if Python 3 is set as the default Python version, then running `python` will use Python 3

## Running IDLE from the terminal

If you have IDLE installed, then:

- `idle2` opens IDLE for Python version 2
- `idle3` opens IDLE for Python version 3 (unless you change the default python)

## Changing the default Python version

If you want Python 3 to be the default Python version, then take a look at this SO question: [How to set Python's default version to 3.3 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x) Be aware that there are some disadvantages and things to work around, so I advise you to read the entire article if you do so.

Comment: I know that if I wanted to use the terminal shell for python then I would use "python3" instead of "python".  What about if I want to acess and run scripts through the terminal?

Comment: If you wanted the script to be run in python version 3, then `python3 /path/to/my/script.py`

Comment: Ok I understand.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To run idle from command line Type `idle3` in the terminal for `Python 3` idle and if you want to run `Python 2` idle, type `idle` in the terminal .

Similarly, if you need to run a script or python prompt from terminal you should type `python3` when you want to use `Python 3` and `python` when you want to run `Python 2`.