# Downloaded Python 3.6 but terminal is still saying I'm using python 2.7.12

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, installation

I have looked for Python 2.7.12 in my apps and docs but I can't find it... 
I'm using a macbook pro.
I can see Python 3.6 in my applications so I don't know why the terminal isn't referring to this one.

I want to get started learning django but I don't think it will be possible if I don't use Python 3.5 or later.

is there a way to tell the terminal to use 3.6 instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python's default version to 3.3 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x)

Comment: You can develop with 2.7 its really not a problem, I do it as well. Do you have a running project? what Version is it in?

Answer (score 1):

Open the text editor like `nano` , `vim` or `gedit` and open the `.bashrc` file ,

`nano ~/.bashrc`

and create the bash alias,

To do so add the following line into the `.bashrc` file:

`alias python='/usr/bin/python3.6'`

Save the file and re-open the terminal.

**Edit:**

Similarly, if you don't want to create the direct alias.

As @exprator suggested above you can also use `python` command for `python 2` and `python3` to use `Python 3` version

Answer (score 1):

Just use python in terminal for python 2.7 and type python3 to use python 3.6 when you need

Answer (score 0):

1. . ~/.bashrc
2. alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4'

Comment: Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you shouldn't use the default environment to develop. Instead, you have to use Virtualenv