# environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed pyspark recently. It was installed correctly. When I am using following simple program in python, I am getting an error.

```
>>from pyspark import SparkContext
>>sc = SparkContext()
>>data = range(1,1000)
>>rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
>>rdd.collect()
```

while running the last line I am getting error whose key line seems to be

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 4]18/01/15 14:36:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

I have the following variables in .bashrc

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python3
```

I am using Python 3.

Comment: I think the error is related with different version of python usage in the master and the worker(s). Please check the python versions. All must be the same.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By the way, if you use PyCharm, you could add `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to run/debug configurations per image below
[image]

Comment: Pycharm reads the bashrc, however, and that's really the preferred solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind sharing, but it seems that custom configuration has priority over system wide config?

Comment: Yes, the IDE variables override system ones

Comment: if you're using pycharm,  @cricket_007 's way is the preferred way because you will hopefully have a virtualenv per project therefore you would like to set these env variables per project. you can set a default value for these env vars under the defaults section. Like this you don't need to edit these env vars per run configuration

Answer (score 45):

This may happen also if you're working within an environment. In this case, it may be harder to retrieve the correct path to the python executable (and anyway I think it's not a good idea to hardcode the path if you want to share it with others).

If you run the following lines at the beginning of your script/notebook (at least before you create the SparkSession/SparkContext) the problem is solved:

```py
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

Package `os` allows you to set global variables; package `sys` gives the string with the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter.

Comment: This is the proper answer. I recommend running `!echo $PYSPARK_PYTHON $PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` before and after running it, to check it took effect.

Answer (score 31):

You should set the following environment variables in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

If `spark-env.sh` doesn't exist, you can rename `spark-env.sh.template`

Comment: I couldn't find a python3 folder in '/opt/spark' but there was a python folder. So I modified this line as 
    export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python

Comment: There is a python folder in `opt/spark`, but that is not the right folder to use for `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`. Those two variables need to point to the folder of the actual Python executable. It is located in `/user/bin/python` or `/user/bin/python2.7` by default

Comment: If you do not want to run different versions of Python on the driver and on the execut ors you only need to configure `PYSPARK_PYTHON` since it defines the version for both driver and executors https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment

Comment: It suffices to apply the changes to the driver machine

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue, and I set both variable in `.bash_profile`

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

But My problem is still there.

Then I found out the problem is that my default python version is python 2.7 by typing `python --version`

So I solved the problem by following below page:
[How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Answer (score 3):

Just run the code below in the very beginning of your code. I am using Python3.7. You might need to run `locate python3.7` to get your Python path.

```
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7"
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7"
```

Comment: Adding those 2 as env vars (to bash_profile.sh) solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to study PySpark, and that's what worked for me.
Find where `python3` is installed doing in a terminal:

```
which python3
```

Here is pointing to `/usr/bin/python3`.
Now in the the beginning of the notebook (or `.py` script), do:

```
import os

# Set spark environments
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3'
```

Restart your notebook session and it should works!

Answer (score 1):

## Apache-Spark 2.4.3 on Archlinux

I've just installed `Apache-Spark-2.3.4` from [Apache-Spark website](https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz), I'm using [Archlinux distribution](https://www.archlinux.org/), it's simple and lightweight distribution. So, I've installed and put the `apache-spark` directory on `/opt/apache-spark/`, now it's time to export our environment variables, remember, I'm using Archlinux, so take in mind to using your `$JAVA_HOME` for example.

### Importing environment variables

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre' >> /home/user/.bashrc
echo 'export SPARK_HOME=/opt/apache-spark'  >> /home/user/.bashrc
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH'  >> /home/user/.bashrc
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH'  >> /home/user/.bashrc
source ../.bashrc
```

#### Testing

```
emanuel@hinton ~ $ echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre' >> /home/emanuel/.bashrc
emanuel@hinton ~ $ echo 'export SPARK_HOME=/opt/apache-spark'  >> /home/emanuel/.bashrc
emanuel@hinton ~ $ echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH'  >> /home/emanuel/.bashrc
emanuel@hinton ~ $ echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH'  >> /home/emanuel/.bashrc
emanuel@hinton ~ $ source .bashrc 
emanuel@hinton ~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun 24 2019, 04:54:02) 
[GCC 9.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
>>>
```

Everything it's working fine since you correctly imported the environment variables for `SparkContext`.

#### Using Apache-Spark on Archlinux via DockerImage

For my use purposes I've created a Docker image with `python`, `jupyter-notebook` and `apache-spark-2.3.4`

running the image

```
docker run -ti -p 8888:8888 emanuelfontelles/spark-jupyter
```

just go to your browser and type

```
http://localhost:8888/tree
```

and will prompted a authentication page, come back to terminal and copy the token number and voila, will have Archlinux container running a Apache-Spark distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pycharm , Got to Run - > Edit Configurations and click on Environment variables to add as below(basically the PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON should point to the same version of Python) . This solution worked for me .Thanks to the above posts.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\Program Files\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop2"
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

This worked for me in a jupyter notebook as the os library makes our life easy in setting up the environment variables. Make sure to run this cell befor running the sparksession.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to see for people, that instead of having to set a specific path  /usr/bin/python3 that you can do this:

I put this line in my ~/.zshrc

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.8
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.8
```

When I type in python3.8 in my terminal I get Python3.8 going.  I think it's because I installed pipenv.

Another good website to reference to get your SPARK_HOME is https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-pyspark-on-your-computer-9c7180075617
(for permission denied issues use sudo mv)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **Download and Install Java (Jre)**
**2.**  **It has two options, you can choose one of the following solution:-**

**## -------- Temporary Solution -------- ##**
Just put the **path** in your **jupyter notebook** in the following **code** and **RUN IT EVERYTIME**:-

```
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = r"C:\Users\LAPTOP0534\miniconda3\envs\pyspark_v3.3.0"

os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = r"C:\Users\LAPTOP0534\miniconda3\envs\pyspark_v3.3.0"

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333"
```

***----OR----***

**## -------- Permanent Solution -------- ##**
**Set above 3 variables in your Environment Variable.**

[image: Environment Variables]

I have gone through many answers but nothing works for me.
But both of these resolution worked for me. This has resolved my error.
**Thanks**

Answer (score -3):

I tried two methods for the question. the method in the picture can works.

[add environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf2HR.png)

```html
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7;PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```