# Spark dataframe write to JSON showing NULL ourput

Tags: json, azure, pyspark

I am extracting JSON data from a API and trying to write on Azure container path. I am able to display data correctly in notebook, but when i write JSON most of the values are NULL. Any help on where i am going wrong?

```
headers = {
"accept" : "application/json",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
 "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(token)
}

 response_get= requests.get(getURL, headers=headers)
 response_final=response_get.json()
 print("Type:", type(response_final))
 data = json_normalize(response_final)
 df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
 ##df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(stagingpath,mode='overwrite')
 df.coalesce(1).write.json(stagingpath,mode='overwrite')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have reproduced in my environment and followed below process and got expected results as below and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data-sources/mount-azure-blob-storage.html) and [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68288770):**

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3')
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([response.text])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)
df.show()
dbutils.fs.mount( source = "wasbs://mycontainer@myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net", mount_point = "/mnt/mymountpoint", extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.mycontainer.myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net": "SAS"})
```

[image]

**The run below script to write json:**

```
df.coalesce(1).write.json( "/mnt/mymountpoint/vamo.json")
```

[image]

**Output:**

**Click on folder Vammo.json:**

[image]

**Click on part-00xxx:**

[image]

**Then Click on View/Edit:**

[image]