# Cannot connect Visual Studio with Azure Databricks cluster: "Missing Python executable 'python3'

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to use our Azure Databricks clusters in Visual Studio running on a virtual machine. I am following the steps described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect)

**1. Setup cluster**

I set up a cluster with runtime 9.1 and specify the advanced options as should. The port I set to 8787.

[image]

The corresponding Python version for this cluster is 3.8.10:

[image]

**2. Create a conda environment on my virtual machine with the same python version:**

[image]

**3. Activate conda environment:**

[image]

**4. Install databricks-connect where version is the same as the runtime of the newly created cluster**

[image]

**5. Set the configuration for databricks-connect**

Here I specify Host, Token, Cluster ID, Organisation ID and make sure that the port is also 8787. The other
parameters I cannot copy due to privacy issues, but these should all be fine.

[image]

**6. Select the right conda environment in Visual Studio**

[image]

So far everything works like a charm. However, when I now try to create a spark session in visual studio, it gets stuck. It won't execute the last line, but doesn't give an error either.

[image]

When I run `databricks-connect test` I get following output. I have tried specifying the PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variables, but this always results in the error message when running `databricks-connect test` changing to 'cannot find path specified' path when it tests the python command.

[image]

I have also tried adding this the code in visual studio as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260412/environment-variables-pyspark-python-and-pyspark-driver-python):

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

However, nothing helped so far. Is anyone familiar with this sort of error and can help me?

Comment: Please post all you calls and other textual information as text!

Comment: Good point. Sorry.