# How to resolve this error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.showString?

Tags: python, java, sql, pyspark

Currently I'm doing PySpark and working on DataFrame.
I've created a DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataFarme").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")])
df.printSchema()
```

#Output:-

```
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

But when I do `df.show()` its showing error as:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\PRATIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20924/3726558592.py in <module>
----> 1 df.show()

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    492 
    493         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 494             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    495         else:
    496             try:

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (KPI-PratikTrainee executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 481, in main
RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.10, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:713)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:476)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 481, in main
RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.10, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:713)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Same thing occured for `df.collect()`.

But the same thing works perfectly fine in PyCharm once I set these 2 zip files in Project Structure: `py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip, pyspark.zip`

Can anybody tell me how to set these 2 files in Jupyter so that I can run df.show() and df.collect() please?

Comment: This will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260412/environment-variables-pyspark-python-and-pyspark-driver-python

Comment: Ya bro but it works on PyCharm but not in Jupyter why?

Comment: Can you tell me how to set that in Jupyter?

Comment: if you export the env variables according to the answer , that is applicable throughout. Since you are on windows , you can check how to add the environment variables accordingly , and do restart just in case

Comment: So what solution do I found to this is do "pip install pyspark" and "python -m pip install findspark" in anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in this part of the error message:

`RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.10, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.`

You need to have exactly the same Python versions in driver and worker nodes.

Probably a quick solution would be to downgrade your Python version to 3.9 (assuming driver is running on the client you're using).

Answer (score 7):

before running the above code you can manually set the env variable
like this

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

this worked in jupyter notebook for me.

Comment: Also works with Anaconda and poetry if you add it to your code (e.g. IDE: Visual Studio Code)

Answer (score 1):

The log error is pretty clear, python for running spark and python running in your code is different, you will need to set PYSPARK_PYTHON same version as your current python running, otherwise it will get default python in system

Comment: This fixed the error I was having.