# Installing GDB with Python 3 on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: python, gdb, homebrew

I tried to do the following:

```
brew -v install gdb --with-python=python3
```

but I get a warning:

```
Warning: gdb: this formula has no --with-python= option so it will be ignored!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, there is no `--with-python=python3` option. You can obtain all available options with `brew info gdb`. You will obtain:

```
==> Options
--with-all-targets
    Build with support for all targets
--with-guile@2.0
    Build with guile@2.0 support
--with-python
    Use the Homebrew version of Python; by default system Python is used
--with-python@2
    Build with python@2 support
--with-version-suffix
    Add a version suffix to program
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `--with-python` option.

```
--with-python
    Use the Homebrew version of Python; by default system Python is used
```

Try to `brew -v install gdb --with-python` after set your deafult python version.

- [How to set Python's default version to 3.3 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x)