# /usr/local/bin has precedence over usr/bin : why is python still python2?

Tags: python, shell, unix, homebrew, symlink

I brew-installed python on my mac, and put `usr/local/bin` before `usr/bin` in my `PATH`, but `python --version` still gives me `Python 2.7.10` while I want my default version to be `Python 3.6.4` (which is the answer to `python3 --version`, so it's definitely installed). Also, I can't find `Python 3.6.4` in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`, if I list the content of the folder it just gives me `2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 Current`. How do I change that without causing any problem to my computer?

Comment: What does `which -a python` say?

Comment: `which -a python` will print all matching pathnames. If you are then sure it is in your path, you can check with `echo $PATH` if the python 3 version precedes the python 2.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python's default version to 3.3 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x)