# Mac: How can I use Python 3.7 in my command line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

How can I use Python 3.7 in my command line?

My Python interpreter is active on Python 3.7 and my python.pythonPath is `/usr/local/bin/python3`, though my Python version in my command line is 2.7. I've already installed Python 3.7 on my mac.

```
lorenzs-mbp:Python lorenzkort$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open tab "Terminal" in your VSCode then your default python is called (in your case python2).

If you want to use python3.7 try to use following command:

```
python3 --version
```

Or just type the full path to the python folder:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 yourscript.py
```

In case you want to change default python interpreter, then follow this accepted anwser: [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `python3` instead of `python` for running any commands you want to run then it will use the python3 version interpreter.

Also if you are using `pip` then use `pip3`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a complete guide in setting up Visual Studio code for python 
[Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)