# Wing101 is defaulting to python 2.7 even though I have the latest version installed on my Mac

Tags: python, macos, wing-ide

I installed Python 3.7 for my Mac Book Pro and in Wing101 it still uses Python 2.7.. anyone who can help me out?

Comment: I have a PC Laptop and I use Python3. perfectly fine.

Comment: "You should verify [Wing] can actually use Python3." I am stating that Wing can use Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18425379/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wing 101, you can set the Python being used in the Configure Python dialog from the Edit menu, by setting the Python Executable.  Wing 101 version 6+ should really be finding and using the latest Python installation, although maybe it's installed in a place that it isn't found automatically.  Wing version 5 prefers Python 2 because it's fairly old and that made more sense at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [`https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

> pyenv lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python. It's
>   simple, unobtrusive, and follows the UNIX tradition of single-purpose
>   tools that do one thing well.

Quite useful tool for managing different versions of Python on your machine.

Happy Coding! :)