# On a MAC: Python: Terminal not the same as my PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pycharm

On my MAC, in terminal/command line when I type:
python --version

I get:

Python 2.7.10

but when on my PyCharm I type:

```
import sys 
print (sys.version)
```

I get:

Python 3.7.1.

Why it's not the same?
What are the steps to fix it on a MAC?

I've tried the commands below, but it doesn't work:

> > sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
> >     sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7.1

Then:

> > python --version

I still get:

> > Python 2.7.10

Comment: because you didn't set the python environment same in system and pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425592/1289629

In pycharm, I believe, in preferences you've (or by default) the latest version of Python is set.

Setting up the alias should help you.