# Mac uses default python 2.7.10 not installed Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have tried to uninstall the Anaconda and re-install again.

But when I verified the installation, the python environment is still using the default python 2.7.10.   From terminal:

```
username ~ $ conda list
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# packages in environment at /Users/username/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2019.03                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0  


username ~ $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And my .bash_profile is as below:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

And I guess it also causes that when I used terminal to launch the Jupyter Notebook, it also uses the python 3, the jupyter can execute `pip list` but when execute `conda list`, it will prompt:

```
ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use ``%pip install`` instead.
```

The environment of jupyter launched by Anaconda navigator can execute both `pip list` and `conda list`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425592/8008686

Comment: anaconda requires you to activate an environment

Comment: Also, changing your default can break a lot of things.

Comment: @Nullman I think you are right, I activate the environment and it works!

Comment: @DMellon I have tried this before, but it didn't work, but still thanks.