# Command line operation fails to parse f-string and python 3 print parameters

Tags: python-3.x

This code works fine when I run it in my PyCharm IDE…

argnotparse.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello world')
    world = 'world'
    print(f'Hello {world}')
    print('Hello', 'world', sep=' ', end='\n')
```

It produces the expected output of…

```
argnotparse.py"
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
```

but if I run it from the command line I see…

```
$ python argnotparse.py
  File "argnotparse.py", line 5
    print(f'Hello {world}')
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My first thought was that something in python's command line parser wasn't updated with the f-strings in python v3.6. So I commented that line out and tried again…

```
$ python argnotparse.py
  File "argnotparse.py", line 6
    print('Hello', 'world', sep=' ', end='\n')
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This ruled out my idea that the argparse module had not been updated as its tutorial demonstrates this python v3 print statement with 'end' as a parameter. (It's in the section titled 'Getting a little more advanced'.)

Why is this happening?

p.s. I'm running python 3.7

--**edit**--

See ['How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Comment: Try `python -V` to see what version you're actually running - it clearly isn't 3.7 as you think.

Comment: It's so long since I had anything knowingly to do with python 2 (I never downloaded it onto this machine) that I didn't notice the argparse tutorial clearly shows the correct command as 'python3 prog.py'. Ty.

Comment: Was the [argparse] tag needed?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @hpaulj. The tutorial is 'Argparse Tutorial' from the python manual. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1
I have removed the  `argparse` tag because this problem was not caused by that module.