# How do I make python 3.7 my default python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python 3.6 and python 3.7 installed on my Mac. When I type python3 --version in terminal, output is "Python 3.6.0" . Maybe it would be better just to uninstall python 3.6? Then how do I do that properly? I spent quite some time googling this and results are mostly about changing default system python from 2.7 to 3 **which is not what I want.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: command not found. Could it be because of new shell on Mac - zsh? Edit: Seems like update-alternatives doesn't work on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a Python version management tool like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Then you could install your version of choice and set it as global default with

```sh
pyenv versions  # List versions available to pyenv
pyenv global <version>  # Set global default version
```