# How do i change my python version on terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

[pic of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/939Rt.png)

I've installed MAMP and python 2.7 before. But I've deleted both of them. But why are they still there? And how to change my default python to 3.7? My pycharm couldn't even detect the python 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Comment: Don't post pics of text but insert the text into your question; such text includes terminal output. Pics are not searchable, amendable etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit bash_profile
>       $  nano ~/.bash_profile
>   Add Python Alias
>       $  alias python='python3'
>   Reload bash_profile
>       $  source ~/.bash_profile
>   Check version
>       $  python --version