# How to set Python3 as a default python version on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-catalina

Is there a way to set the Python 3.8.3 as the default Python version on macOS Catalina -- version 10.15.2?

Steps I have done:

1. Look where it is installed.

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

The output I got is something like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  36 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  39 May 20 12:43 /usr/local/bin/python-build -> ../Cellar/pyenv/1.2.18/bin/python-build
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  43 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  37 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  44 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python2-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python2-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  39 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  46 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  69 May 20 12:22 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  76 May 20 12:22 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  71 May 20 12:22 /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel  78 May 20 12:22 /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  37 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/pythonw -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  38 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/pythonw2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/pythonw2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeena  admin  40 Mar 20  2019 /usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/pythonw2.7
```

2. Change the default python symlink to the version I want to use from above:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Then I checked the version again:

```
python --version
```

And I got it as --> `Python 2.7.16`

I also tried `alias python="/usr/bin/python3.8"` but sadly it's still Python 2.7.16

Comment: as per the top answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x this is not advised and could break some things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Comment: @KevinWang I tried ```alias``` way too as I mentioned in my question it didn't work.

Comment: so `> /usr/bin/python3.8` correctly starts the python3 REPL, but `> alias python="/usr/bin/python3.8"` followed by `> python` starts the python2 REPL?

Comment: @KevinWang Yes you're correct

Comment: that is strange indeed.  What shell are you using?  Can you edit the question and copy-paste from shell exactly the commands and outputs you ran when you tried the aliasing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can run the following commands :

```
rm /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python
```

And in your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc, put

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then start a new terminal to test

```
echo $PATH
```

to make sure /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin

Comment: This saved me time today.. Thanks for the sleek answer!