# How to set Python3 as default in MacOS Monterey (Macbook Air M1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, apple-m1

Monterey(M1) has python2 and python3 preinstalled. But the python2 is set as default, I want to change it to python3. How to change the default version to python3?
[image]

[image]In my Macbook Air having

Comment: not sure if it would break some existing functionality under the hood by changing `python` to point to `python3`. what is wrong with just typing `python3`?

Comment: you would need to add symbolic(as suggested by Saliou DJIBRILA) and then export that. These two posts will give you some more details [python3 before python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941873/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac) and [symbolic link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 14):

**If you are on Mac M1**

**Steps**

```
1. $ brew install python
2. $ sudo ln -s -f /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
3. Restart your terminal.
4. $ python --version
```

**If you are on Intel Mac**

**Steps**

```
1. $ brew install python
2. $ ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.<your version> /usr/local/bin/python
3. Close Terminal and test version 
4. $ python --version
```

Comment: `ln: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory` on M1 Monterey 12.3

Answer (score 4):

You can use symbolic link:
`ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: permission denied?....

Comment: Doesn't work: 
`ln: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory` on M1 Monterey 12.3

Comment: This is the only solution that worked in my case, thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided it is not possible to say if `/usr/bin/python` is already a symlink. You can check all the python versions in that directory and see if it is a symlink or not.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

**If `python` is an existing symlink**

In the case that `python` is a symlink, you should be able to change the symlink to link to `python3` as already suggested here, -s for soft, -f for force to overwrite an existing symlink.

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

If the operation is not permitted you will need to create it as root. If this is good solution I do not know, so use my answer with precaution.

```
sudo -i
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Check if the right version is recognised

```
where python
python -V
```

**From MacOS Monterey 12.3**

[From MacOS Monterey Version 12.3, python2 is no longer preinstalled](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/01/28/apple-removing-python-2-in-macos-12-3/), and is shipped with Python 3.8.9. Therefore `python` is not in use and a symlink can be used without concerns regarding `python2`.

```
python -V
zsh: command not found: python
python2 -V
zsh: command not found: python2
python3 -V
Python 3.8.9
```