# How to prevent terminal from picking up old python version 2.7.16 after installing 3.8

Tags: python, macos

I have followed all the possible suggestion on stack overflow with no success.
When I run `python --version` the result :

```
Home-Macbook-Pro:~ pcmac$ python

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun  5 2020, 22:59:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit ()
```

How can I uninstall or force terminal to use Python version 3.8 please
Also the IDLE is running on old Python version 2.7.16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Python's default version to 3.x on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this solution worked for me:

I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.6 and used homebrew to install python 3.8.5.

All I did was type 'nano .zprofile' in terminal and then typing: alias python='python3' and saving it by hitting Ctrl+o and then Enter.

Comment: Worked for me. Just added that alias to my bash_profile.