# Trouble installing Django for first time

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal

I am trying to use Django on mac to develop a website backend using python.

I installed Django 3.1.5 and when I try to upgrade (to 3.1.5) it says 'requirement already satisfied' so I can tell 3.1.5 is installed

However when I type
`python -m django --version` into terminal, it returns 1.11.29

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should install it with `pip3` (the package manager for `Python3`), and thus run it with `python3 -m django --version`.

Comment: Okay thank you that worked

Comment: I think you can alter the symbolic link of `python`, and let it point to `python3` instead of `python2`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18425379/67579

Comment: Thank you a lot!