# f"This connection is using {tls_version} which is now "

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting this error message `f"This connection is using {tls_version} which is now "` when I ran my python code using `python main.py`.

My code:

```
import mysql.connector as connector

con = connector.connect(host='localhost',port='3306',user='root',password='dfadfsasfd',database='python')

print(con)
```

[image]

I already tried to install this package `pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf` but it still shows me same error message.
Anyone please help me with this!

Comment: You are using Python 2.7. You need Python 3.

Comment: You are executing Python3 library using Python2 interpreter.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: ...use `python3 main.py` instead of `python main.py`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x